# Why does my symbol not have external linkage?

Tags: assembly, linker, clang

I'm trying to build `coro.c` using Clang+LTO (it works fine without LTO).

When I link together the final binary, I get the following error:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
void ()* @coro_transfer
```

The symbol is defined in `coro.h` as:

```
#if __i386__ || __x86_64__
extern void __attribute__ ((__noinline__, __regparm__(2)))
#else
extern void __attribute__ ((__noinline__))
#endif
coro_transfer (coro_context *prev, coro_context *next);
```

and in `coro.c` as:

```
  asm (
       "\t.text\n"
       #if _WIN32 || __CYGWIN__ || __MACH__
       "\t.globl _coro_transfer\n"
       "_coro_transfer:\n"
       #else
       "\t.globl coro_transfer\n"
       "coro_transfer:\n"
       #endif
```

It seems to me that it does have (or should) have global linkage. Is this a bug with LTO, or is there something wrong with the assembly definition?

I checked with nm and noticed the symbol was first undefined and then defined. I guess that's because of the declaration in the header but it's not technically a C function in the implementation.

```
coro.c.o:
         U abort
00000000 T coro_create
00000000 T coro_stack_alloc
00000000 T coro_stack_free
         U coro_transfer
00000000 T coro_transfer
         U mmap
         U mprotect
         U munmap
         U sysconf
```

Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Why are you using inline assembly to create this symbol? This seems like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried marking the symbol as `.type coro_transfer,@function`? clang might be confused because you didn't specify a symbol type. I can't test this on my own because you didn't give us enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Because it's a coroutine transfer function, it's not executing normal stack setup code. I will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Try defining the function using `__attribute__((naked))` instead of a manual symbol. Or write the whole function in assembly in a separate file; generally, inline assembly should be avoided as it can cause the kind of weird problems you experience.

Comment: I didn't write the original code and I need to make it work the best I can until I can allocate time to rewrite it. LTO is not essential, but a nice to have.

Comment: LTO doesn't do anything with functions written in assembly, so you don't loose anything by moving your assembly function into an assembly file.